# what sort of format should be for my csv data to act as multi labels in keras/tensorflow

Tags: csv, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have a dataset in csv format. one columns is images and the other one are it's corresponding labels. I have done with single labels and multi label classification problems but this data looks impossible for me to convert to a multi class that's why I am asking here. Please first check the data format below

```
 |  uid  | labels |
 | --- | --- |
 | 1.jpg | The cardiac silhouette and mediastinum size are within normal limits. There is no pulmonary edema. There is no focal consolidation. There are no XXXX of a pleural effusion. There is no evidence of pneumothorax. |
 | 2.jpg | Borderline cardiomegaly. Midline sternotomy XXXX. Enlarged pulmonary arteries. Clear lungs. Inferior XXXX XXXX XXXX.
 | 3.jpg | There are diffuse bilateral interstitial and alveolar opacities consistent with chronic obstructive lung disease and bullous emphysema. There are irregular opacities in the left lung apex, that could represent a cavitary lesion in the left lung apex.There are streaky opacities in the right upper lobe, XXXX scarring. The cardiomediastinal silhouette is normal in size and contour. There is no pneumothorax or large pleural effusion. |
```

I want to split the labels with (.) and (,) so that they will act as multi labels (each image will have many labels from 5-7) and then I want to convert these into numpy array or any sort which I can feed to my image classifier models.

Problems is to split and convert this data in such a form that can be used by image classifier models.

Thank You

Comment: Do you have a pre-defined set of sentences (thus labels)? It seems like sentences from row to row haven't been reused. If so, no two records would have same label?

Comment: I used labels in my question to somehow making it closely to an image classification problem but there will be thousands sets of sentences if I try the same way as previous multi label classification approaches. I though if there would be any other technical coding way to take an image and it's corresponding sentences and making them as it's labels before applying pre-processing and feeding them into the model.

Comment: Are there any models that can generate multi captions from a single image?

Comment: You can generate multi captions if you want as that's just having `n` heads to do `n` captions. But what I don't understand is how do you separate responsibilities of each head? How do you ask each head to generate a caption about some particular attribute? If so, you need some meta label for each caption to say what that caption is about and use that label to choose a head for that caption.